# Can I redefine the keys on my macbook pro keyboard?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I have an older Macbook Pro that I've been able to upgrade the OS on in order to keep things up to date.  I just opened the back in order to fix a problem with the fan and all the sudden the enter and right shift keys don't work. I tried to use an old Apple USB keyboard and it's not being seen.  I'd like to find a way to redefine the keys or something so that I can simulate pressing enter.
I've been able to use voice commands and say "new line" but that kinda sucks.  Maybe use the TAB key for newline or enter?  Can that be done?
Maybe something in Accessibility?

Also, why can't I use an older USB keyboard on the Macbook?